# AWS Lambda: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-iam

I have a lambda function making a s3 HeadObject call. Even though there has been a custom policy made for this lambda function, I keep getting an 403 error whenever this HeadObject call is made. There is specifically;

```
An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

My policy very clearly allows GetObject calls for the bucket in question. Not sure what the problem is. I have triple check that it all lines up. The line in question is:

```
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    local_file_path = '/tmp/' + key_name.split('/')[-1] + '_REMOTE.json'
    response = s3.head_object(Bucket=environ['OUTPUT_BUCKET'], Key=OUTPUT_FILE_NAME)
```

Let me know if I can provide more info to help

Comment: and the file exists ?

Comment: @b.b3rn4rd the file doesn't exist yet, but does that mean it will return a error? For context I'm implementing this file given by amazon https://github.com/awslabs/aws-waf-security-automations/blob/master/source/log-parser/log-parser.py

Comment: yeah mate that's expected

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Since you said the file is missing its an expected behaviour if you're missing `s3:ListBucket` permissions

> You need the s3:GetObject permission for this operation.  For more information, go to Specifying Permissions in a Policy in the Amazon Simple Storage Service Developer Guide. If the object you request does not exist, the error Amazon S3 returns depends on whether you also have the s3:ListBucket permission.
>
> If you have the s3:ListBucket permission on the bucket, Amazon S3 will
>   return a HTTP status code 404 ("no such key") error.
>
> If you don’t have the s3:ListBucket permission, Amazon S3 will return
>   a HTTP status code 403 ("access denied") error.

Link to the [doco](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html)

There is also a "different" eventual consistency behaviour for doing `HEAD` **before** uploading the object

> Amazon S3 Data Consistency Model
>   Amazon S3 provides read-after-write consistency for PUTS of new objects in your S3 bucket in all regions with one caveat. The caveat is that if you make a HEAD or GET request to the key name (to find if the object exists) before creating the object, Amazon S3 provides eventual consistency for read-after-write.

Comment: Okay I'll add that permission and give it another try. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure this was the solution. I just got it to run when I created everything in my test environment. For some reason it only works half the time and I'm not understanding why.

Comment: I'm thinking it might be a regional thing? My test environment succeeded in us-west-1, but I'm having problems in us-east-1. Not sure why that would matter though.

Comment: I was essentially chasing a red herring on this issue. You were correct in that it was an expected error. I was incorrectly associating it with errors that cloudwatch was reporting to me.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution on this [link](https://intellipaat.com/community/2808/aws-cli-s3-a-client-error-403-occurred-when-calling-the-headobject-operation-forbidden), so all the credit goes to the author.

Basically you might need to check you have the right permissions ( `s3:GetObject` and `s3:ListBucket` at least ) for the operation and the resource expression matches the ARN plus a path e.g this -> `"Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*"` rather than this -> `"Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME"`.

Answer (score 1):

I have just encountered this issue for keys with square brackets (e.g `[x][y]abcd.ext`).
Upon renaming the keys, everything proceeded to work correctly - 403 error resolved.

That was an incredibly non-intuitive solution.

Answer (score 0):

`s3:ListBucket` is a bucket specific permission so iamInlinePolicies should be like this

```
    Action:
      - s3:ListBucket
      - s3:PutObject
      - s3:GetObject
      - s3:DeleteObject
    Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*'
  - Effect: Allow
    Action:
      - s3:ListBucket
    Resource: 'arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME'
```

adding resource like this `arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*` will provide you to perform operation inside the bucket and for ListBucket, resource are only the bucket `arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME`